# How can I set the actual scale of axes in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, scaling, axes

I have 4 sets of 3D scatter data that i want to plot in MATLAB subplots. However, I would like the scale to be the same in each—so that sizes in each dataset can be roughly visually compared between plots.

What makes this slightly difficult is that the limits for each plot are arbitrary, so cannot be set to a specific value.

Is there a way to set the *scale* of a MATLAB plot explicitly? Something like "set each pixel to be 4 units" would be great.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as changing the limits? The number of pixels in the plot is fixed, you can't change it right.  So changing the scale will change the limits or vise-versa.

Comment: do you want to set each subplot to have the same range of limits, but different absolute limits... for e.g., subplot1 is from -10 to 20 and subplot2 is from -50 to -20

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to set them all to be the same as whatever the scale of the first one happened to be, just do this:

```
<Plot your first plot>
limx = get(gca, 'XLim');
limy = get(gca, 'YLim');
<Plot your second plot>
set(gca, 'XLim', limx);
set(gca, 'YLim', limy);
```